# Jmeter - Retry count reduce it and time out

Tags: jmeter

how can i reduce the retry from 30 .
when I get the below error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than 30 retries - stopping with exception
at kg.apc.jmeter.timers.VariableThroughputTimer.stopTest(VariableThroughputTimer.java:299) ~[jmeter-plugins-tst-2.5.jar:?]

also, how can I reduce the session time out for the HTTP requests made. ?

Answer (score 1):

1. This `30` tries number is [hard-coded](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/plugins/tst/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/timers/VariableThroughputTimer.java#L298) therefore the only way to "reduce" this is to amend the number of tries, recompiling the plugin and replacing the .jar in the "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation.

   The error you're getting means that the Throughput Shaping Timer tries to stop the test gracefully and fails to do it so it terminates it forcefully. You could take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) and see what exactly your threads are doing and where they're stuck.

   Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as one of the common reasons for this behaviour is improper JMeter tuning for high loads or lack of resources like CPU or RAM.
2. If you want to specify the connect/response timeout for JMeter's HTTP requests it can be done at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

   [image]